# Observable not acting synchronously

Tags: typescript, promise, rxjs, axios, rxjs6

I am using the `defer` to convert a promise (`getAuthToken`) to an observable. Then using `subscribe` to assign the `token` variable to the response.

*new to observables, but tried as long as I could alone

I've tried using `from` to convert the promise, although not really a solution to the problem, but did try using it. Also used pipe(map())...

I am referring to this [article](https://itnext.io/javascript-promises-vs-rxjs-observables-de5309583ca2) that explains the observables should be synchronous. Although my example does not seem to act that way.

```js
getFakeConfig() {
  const token = defer(getAuthToken).subscribe(res => {
    console.log('res =', res)
    return res
  })

  console.log('token =', token)

  return {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    },
  }
}

makeRequest() {
  const config = this.getFakeConfig()
  console.log('config =', config)
}
```

```js
// in a different file, basically what it does
export const getAuthToken = () => {
  return axios(options)
    .then(response => response.data.token)
}
```

Hitting `makeRequest()` outputs:

```
token = Subscriber {
  ...
}

config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: '[object Object]'
  }
}

res = token234234234
```

I expect it to output:

```
res = token234234234

token = token234234234

config = {
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'token234234234'
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot get the value of a promise synchronously, period.  Observables cannot magically extract it.

Comment: @SLaks you can use async/await to get a promise value synchronously.

Comment: @bryan60: No; you can use `await` to _make your function asynchronous as well_.

Answer (score 1):

Defer is not the option, [defer docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer).

The best you can do in order your code to behave **synchronously** is to use `async/await` (fits perfectly with **promises**),

```
async getFakeConfig() {
  const token = await getAuthToken();
  console.log('token =', token);

  return {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    },
  }
}
```

But if you still want to use `Observables` you have to get use to its asynchronously behaviour,

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
getFakeConfig() {
    return from(getAuthToken).pipe(map(token => {
        console.log('token =', token);
        return {
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `${token}`,
          },
        }
    }));
}
```

and since `getFakeConfig` returns an `Observable`,

```
makeRequest() {
  this.getFakeConfig().subscribe(config => {
      console.log('config =', config)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're misunderstanding what is meant by "observables execute synchronously"... and I don't blame you because that's an exceptionally confusing / deceptive way of describing an observable.

the truth is that if everything underlying an observable call is indeed synchronous, then the observable will execute synchronously, whereas a promise will execute asynchronously regardless of what underlies it. Since you have asynchronous things underlying your observable in this case, it will execute asynchronously.

Best practice is to always treat your observables as though they are executing async regardless of whether they will or not.